# css footer not displaying at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css

this is my code for my footer, how can i make it display at the bottom of the page rather than right underneath my content above it?

```
/*footer */
#footer .column {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}

#footer .column div {
    margin: 5px;
    height: 200px;
    background: #eeeeee;
}

<div id="footer">
    <div class="column"><div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div></div></div>
    <div class="column"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

Note: This does NOT need to be a fixed footer

Comment: What is the difference between a "fixed footer" and always displaying the footer at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Did my answer resolve your issue?

Comment: @showdev A fixed footer is sticky. Bottom of the page means there's no div below the footer, but it's not always there if you're scrolled up.

Answer (score 52):

There's really two main options:

1. **Fixed Footer** - the footer *always is visible* at the bottom of the page
2. **Pushed Footer** - the footer is *pushed* to the bottom of the page even when the content doesn't fill the window

The easier of the two is the fixed footer.

### Fixed Footer

To make the footer fixed, in CSS set the footer's position to fixed `position:fixed` and position the footer to the bottom of the page `bottom:0px`. Here's a code snippet from [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/fixed-footer/).

```
#footer {
   position:fixed;
   left:0px;
   bottom:0px;
   height:30px;
   width:100%;
   background:#999;
}

/* IE 6 */
* html #footer {
   position:absolute;
   top:expression((0-(footer.offsetHeight)+(document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : document.body.clientHeight)+(ignoreMe = document.documentElement.scrollTop ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : document.body.scrollTop))+'px');
}
```

### Pushed Footer

A pushed footer is a bit trickier. Here's [a great graphic](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) showing why the footer doesn't stay at the bottom of the page when there isn't enough content:

[image: Pushed Footer Issue Visual]

Basically, the problem is happening because the footer element is 'pushed' under the element that is above it and the height of that element isn't as long as the height of the page. In order to fix this, you need to make sure that the footer gets 'pushed' down the full height of the page (minus the height of your footer).

Here's how to do it:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="header"></div>
   <div id="body"></div>
   <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   height:100%;
}
#container {
   min-height:100%;
   position:relative;
}
#header {
   background:#ff0;
   padding:10px;
}
#body {
   padding:10px;
   padding-bottom:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
}
#footer {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   width:100%;
   height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
   background:#6cf;
}
```

Here's a more detailed [tutorial on how to do it](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page) as well as the source of the code above.

And here's a [working demo of the code](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/bottom-footer-demo.htm) from the same source.

Comment: Yeah, pretty much it. This footer css can be applied to anything. `margin-bottom:0px;` or just `bottom:0px` will work, but if you want your header to be always at the top, it can be done with `top:0px`. It can be applied with anything, with this tags `left, right, top, bottom, or margin-[position]` where `position` = left, right, top or bottom. I think you should mention that @Scott to prevent duplicate questions. Good job :D

Comment: Be sure not to be like me and accidentally write `body { min-height: 100% }` It does not work, in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 9):

Bootstrap have an example of a footer that sticks to the bottom of the page here:
https://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Here is the CSS:

```
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
}
body {
  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  /* Set the fixed height of the footer here */
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
```

Then in the HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">

</footer>
```

Answer (score 5):

**Fixed your footer in bottom with cool effect**

Check full page design in jsfiddle [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kulbhushancharaya/roweeLLe/7/)

```
<body>
<header>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">link4</a></li>
</ul>
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="demo">
<h1> H1</h1>
<h2> h2</h2>
<h3> h3</h3>
<h4> h4</h4>
<h5> h5</h5>
<h6> h6</h6>
<hr>
<h1> H1</h1>
<h2> h2</h2>
<h3> h3</h3>
<h4> h4</h4>
<h5> h5</h5>
<h6> h6</h6>
<hr>
<h1> H1</h1>
<h2> h2</h2>
<h3> h3</h3>
<h4> h4</h4>
<h5> h5</h5>
<h6> h6</h6>
</div>
</div>
<footer>
    <h1>kulbhushan charaya</h1>
</footer>
</body>
```

and css is

```
body {
    background: #ffffff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    padding:40px 0;
}
header{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  z-index:999;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  background:#fff;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}
header ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: outside none none;
  padding: 5px;
}
header ul li a {
    color: #000000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
footer h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
.wrapper {
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 15px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: tried to use this but it makes links unclickable if the content is not big enough

Answer (score 4):

if anyone is stuck with this again, [this is a modern solution without hacks](https://codepen.io/cbracco/pen/zekgx)

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
  <h1>CSS “Always on the bottom” Footer</h1>

  <p>I often find myself designing a website where the footer must rest at the bottom of the page, even if the content above it is too short to push it to the bottom of the viewport naturally.</p>

  <p>However, if the content is taller than the user’s viewport, then the footer should disappear from view as it would normally, resting at the bottom of the page (not fixed to the viewport).</p>

  <p>If you know the height of the footer, then you should set it explicitly, and set the bottom padding of the footer’s parent element to be the same value (or larger if you want some spacing).</p>

  <p>This is to prevent the footer from overlapping the content above it, since it is being removed from the document flow with <code>position: absolute;</code>.</p>
</div>

<div class="footer">This footer will always be positioned at the bottom of the page, but <strong>not fixed</strong>.</div>
```

CSS:

```
/**
 * Demo Styles
 */

html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom: 6rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif;
}

.demo {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 64px;
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 94%;
}

.demo h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}

/**
 * Footer Styles
 */

.footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by simply using `min-height` on the main `container` of my HTML.

So HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="top-nav">My Nav Bar</div>
    <div class="main-container">
        All my content
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        My footer
    </div>
</body>
```

and then CSS

```
.top-nav {
    height: 4rem;
}
.main-container {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 4rem - 4rem);
}
.footer {
    height: 4rem;
}
```

With SCSS you can use variables to track the top-nav and footer heights and then do something like

```
.main-container {
  min-height: calc(100vh - #{$top-nav-height} - #{$footer-height});
}
```

This is not a *perfect* solution because it won't put your footer *exactly* at the bottom of the viewport but it will push it down to the bottom when the content is too short and prevents the footer from being way up in middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you mean is that you would like the footer to remain at the bottom of the page, even when there is insufficient content on the page to fill the height of the viewport?

If that is the case, you can  use this trick: CSS sticky footer - http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/, http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/ or http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

The sticky footer trick typically relies on declaring a minimum-height on a wrapper div. This means that you will have to reformat your HTML code as follow:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="content">
        /* Main body content */
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    /* Footer content here */
</div>
```

For the CSS:

```
html, body, #wrap {
    height: 100%;
}
#wrap {
    height: auto;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: (footer height);
}
#footer { 
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -(footer height); /* Note the negative value */
    height: (footer height);
    clear:both;
}
```

If your footer may have variable height, you will have to set the bottom padding of `#content`, and top margin of `#footer` with JavaScript. The value depends on the computed height of the `#footer` element itself.

Comment: This is a [link-only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259). Please add context for your link.

Comment: I implemented this code and the footer still remains in the middle of the page if the content does not take up the entire viewport. Are there any exceptions that I might need to know about to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

you may need to set the html element height to 100%, otherwise your page itself will only be the necessary height for your content. I ran into this myself.

Answer (score 0):

```
#main {padding-bottom: 150px;} /* Should have the same value of footer's height */ 
#footer {position: relative; 
margin-top: -150px; /* footer's height */
```

Answer (score 0):

Material Design Bootstrap has a great class: [`fixed-bottom`](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/utilities/position/).  It is what I use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the parent  after the footer automatically sets their position at the bottom.

if you can't add content or height in parent div or section of footer after this problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Just use flex-box: By setting the body display to flex and then aligning the footer to flex end. This way the footer will always be the last component at the end.

```css
body {
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: column;
}

footer {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```